# Study whether the turnout $$ is higher than $75\%$ at a significance level of $1\%$

Tags: statistics

The famous pollster Maurice the Cat polled whether the Netherlands should stay in the European Union. 
From a random sample of 1024 citizens it turns out that 250 of them are in favour of a Nexit. 
From the same poll it tured out that $800$ of the $1024$ respondents would vote at a referendum about a departure of the Netherlands from the European Union. 
Let $$ be the actual (still unknown) turnout at a referendum about a Nexit. 
Study whether the turnout $$ is higher than $75\%$ at a significance level of $1\%$: formulate the relevant hypotheses, testing parameter with distribution and motivated conclusion.

I have some problem to formulate the hypothesis for this exercise, can someone help me with this?

**Edit**: 
If I assume $H_0:q=0.75$ and $H_1:q>0.75$ with a significance level $\alpha$ of $0.01$ I can find from the table the critical value that is $2.32$, now knowing that the distribution is a $Bin(1024,0.75)$, how can I proceed?

**Edit 2**: 
$P(X>800)=P\left(Z>\frac{800-1024*0.75}{\sqrt{1024*0.75*(1-0.75)}}\right)=P(Z>2.309)=0.0107$ (from the standard normal table)

**Edit 3**: 
$\alpha=0.01$ correspond to a value of $2.326$ from the normal tables. $\frac{n-1024*0.75}{\sqrt{1024*0.75*(1-0.75)}}=2.326$ $n=800.234$, this number is bigger that $800$ so in my opinion we reject the null hypothesis, it's correct?

Comment: Solution using exact comp. in R: Testing $H_0: q = .75$ vs $H_a: q > .75$ and using poll results as data, one might rej at level 1% if the nr out of 1024 who say they would vote is $\ge$ the 99th percentile $c$ of $\mathsf{Binom}(1024, .75).$  R code `qbinom(.99, 1024, .75)` returns $c=800.$ So one would (just barely) reject $H_0$ and predict that the turnout will exceed 75%. Of course, this depends on the validity of the poll and the assumption that enthusiasm for voting remains unchanged from poll to election day. // I suppose a solution by normal approx is expected in a course not using R.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the comment, I edited the question, now how I can I proceed?

Comment: To start, can you use normal approx to binomial to find $P(X \ge 800)$ for $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(1024, .75)?$ . If this clue is not enough, say what you have covered recently, what you have tried, why you're stuck. In order to provide answers relevant to _you,_ we need to see some engagement from you.

Comment: @BruceET I added edit 2 :)

Comment: Your latest result is very near 1%. If you wanted _exactly_  $0.01$ what number would you substitute for 2.309? That would be the critical value for the normal-approximated test at 1%? Going back to the scale of binomial counts, what number, if any, would you substitute for 800 to get that critical value? (Remember you're dealing with a normal _approximation_ to binomial,) Now maybe put it all together and bravely post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @BruceET I put another edit, is it correct? do I have to do something else? 
If yes, I'll put everything in one answer?

Comment: If your computation is correct the observed 800 (just barely) fails to be larger than your critical value 800.2. So on a very close call, you would not reject at the 1.0% level. But you could reject at the 1.1% level. If the observed value were 801 then you could reject at the 1% level. // You were asked to "study" the situation. There is strong evidence that more than 3/4 of the population will vote in a "Nexit" election, but not quite enough to reject at the 1% level. // Dealing with the discrete binomial dist'n it is not possible to test _precisely_ at the 1% level.// Good luck; won't chat.